# How to choose a method randomly in Java

Tags: java, random, methods, class-method

I have several sort and search methods in a class

```
public static void MetodoBurbuja(int[] A) {
    int i, j, aux;

    for (i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A.length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (A[j + 1] < A[j]) {
                aux = A[j + 1];
                A[j + 1] = A[j];
                A[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void MetodoBurbujaOptimizada(int vector[]) {
    int aux, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (vector[i] < vector[j]) {
                aux = vector[j];
                vector[j] = vector[i];
                vector[i] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And called them from the main class with the variable metbu.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    //llamamos al metodo burbuja
    metodoburbuja2 metbu = new metodoburbuja2();

    for(int i = 0; i < ejec; i++){
    
        int [] inputTenThousand = new int [500000];
        int n = inputTenThousand.length;
        for (int a = 0; a < inputTenThousand.length; a++){
        
            inputTenThousand [a] = (int) (Math.random() * 500000);
            
        }
        
        long time_start, time_end;
        time_start = System.nanoTime(); 

       metbu.MetodoBurbujaOptimizada(inputTenThousand);

        time_end = System.nanoTime();
        
        nanosec = time_end - time_start;
        milsec = nanosec * 0.000001;
        System.out.print(milsec + " ");

    }
```

How could you make one of all these methods be chosen at random?

Any criticism, help or advice, I would appreciate it as you do not have an idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use another Math.random() statement to randomly pick between the two methods with an if statement

So instead of just the solo call:

```
metbu.MetodoBurbujaOptimizada(inputTenThousand);
```

Try using something like:

```
if(Math.random() > 0.5){
    System.out.println("Using MetodoBurbuja");
    metbu.MetodoBurbuja(inputTenThousand);
}
else{
    System.out.println("Using MetodoBurbujaOptimizada");
    metbu.MetodoBurbujaOptimizada(inputTenThousand);
}
```

Hopefully I'm interpreting your question correctly!

As for other pointers, you can use System.currentTimeMillis() instead of nanoseconds and you won't have to convert them into milliseconds.

Comment: run:
...
...
...
0.23149999999999998 Using MetodoBurbuja
0.3705 Using MetodoBurbujaOptimizada
0.23329999999999998 Using MetodoBurbujaOptimizada
0.2258 Using MetodoBurbuja
0.3697 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Use the 2 methods, could you make only 1 of them be chosen? (It is that I not only have 2 methods in the method class, they are like 10 ordering and search methods) and I do not know how to make 1 of them be chosen randomly ...

Comment: @Estenoesodor It's running multiple times because of the big for loop you have around the whole program. Remove that and it will only run once. As for selecting between a lot of different functions, you could set the result from Math.random() to a variable and check for intervals, or use a case statement like the other answer uses.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to generate a random number between 1 and the number of algorithms you want to run inside your for loop and then use that number in a "switch" statement:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    private Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this code would go inside your for-loop:
        int randNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        switch(randNumber) {
            case 1:
                // call method "a" here
                break;
            case 2:
                // call method "b" here
                break;
            // and so forth
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int randNumber = this.randomGenerator.nextInt(10); 

That line of code marks me an error

Comment: Yes - I edited the answer to remove the `this`.